# Java persist a list with multi thread

Tags: java, database, multithreading, collections, persist

I need to create a list to do the following operation:

1. I receive an object from an external queue/topic every microsecond.
2. After doing some operations on the object, I need to persist these objects into database.
3. I am doing the persist in batches of 100 or 1000. The only problem is, persist rate is lower than the incoming message rate. Now I don't want to keep this in a single thread since the persist will slow down the message consumption.
4. My idea is to keep accepting the message objects and adding them to a collection (like a linked list)
5. And keep removing from the other end of the collection in batches of 100 or 1000 and persist into database.
6. What is the right collection to use? How to synchronize this and avoid concurrent modification exceptions?

Below is the code I'm trying to implement with an ArrayList that clears out the list every few seconds while persisting.

```
class myclass{
List persistList;
ScheduledExecutorService persistExecutor;
ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture;
PersistOperation persistOperation;
//Initialize delay, interval
void init(){
scheduledFuture=persistExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new persistOperation(persistList), delay, interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
void execute(msg){
//process the message and add to the persist list
}
class PersistOperation implements Runnable{
List persistList
PersistOperation(List persistList){
//Parameterized constructor
}
run(){
//Copy persistList to new ArrayList and clear persistList
//entity manager persist/update/merge
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> And keep removing from the other end of the collection in batches of 100 or 1000 and persist into database.

This is reasonable so long as multiple threads poll from the collection.

> Below is the code I'm trying to implement with an ArrayList

An `ArrayList` is a bad choice here, as it is not thread-safe and, when removing an element at index `0`, every element to the right of it must be shifted over (an `O(n)` operation).

The collection that you're looking for is called a `Deque`, otherwise known as a double-ended queue. However, because you need the collection to be thread-safe, I recommend using a `ConcurrentLinkedDeque`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will want to use the [LMAX Disruptor framework](https://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/) here. I envision two RingBuffers. You would use the first to accept incoming messages. Your worker(s) would read from the RingBuffer. You would set the size of the RingBuffer to equal your persistence chunk size (eg 100 or 1000). After a worker takes an event from the RingBuffer and processes it, it places a reference to the persisted object into a Queue Collection. Each time the first RingBuffer has been circled once, you allocate a new Queue and place the old Queue into the second RingBuffer. The worker(s) for the second RingBuffer take a Queue object from the RingBuffer, persist all the objects in the Queue, and then move to the next queue. You can tune the size of the second RingBuffer and the worker threads to accommodate the speed at which the database can persist your chunks.

Answer (score 0):

You risk losing messages with that approach, if you have 100 messages receive but not saved, and your application dies, can you afford to lose those messages?
The kind of topic/queue is important here, topics have the advantage of managing this backpressure control, queues are usually there because ordered processing is required.
If you queue/topic is kafka, and you pull messages, kafka can pull batches, and you probably can save batches to the database as well, an only ack the messages to kafka once saved.
If your processing needs to be ordered, you can probably handle some king of reactive approach and tune the db. A queue system can control the flow, usually.